# Create foreign key in MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have table tbl0 and table tbl1. tbl0 has a primary key made from field "Ticker" that I created like this:

```
Sub CreatPrimaryKey()
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "CREATE INDEX TickerID ON tbl0 (Ticker) WITH PRIMARY;"
db.Close
End Sub
```

...which worked fine.

I confirm that I have the primary key by using this:

```
Sub GetPrimaryKeyField()
Call PrimKey("tbl0")
End Sub

Public Sub PrimKey(tblName As String)
'get primary key of tabel
'how to use: Call PrimKey("tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0")
'http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/679509-finding-primary-key-using-vba
'*******************************************
'Purpose: Programatically determine a
' table's primary key
'Coded by: raskew
'Inputs: from Northwind's debug window:
' Call PrimKey("Products")
'Output: "ProductID"
'*******************************************

Dim db As Database
Dim td As TableDef
Dim idxLoop As Index

Set db = CurrentDb
Set td = db.TableDefs(tblName)
For Each idxLoop In td.Indexes
If idxLoop.Primary = True Then
Debug.Print Mid(idxLoop.Fields, 2)
Exit For
End If
Next idxLoop

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

The immediate window prints "Ticker". I'm not sure what happened to "TickerID", but whatever. I get a PK. I then try to create a foreign key relationship between tbl0 and tbl1 by doing this:

```
Sub CreateForeignKey()Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tbl1 " _
        & "ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tbl1_tbl0 " _
        & "FOREIGN KEY (Ticker) REFERENCES tbl0 (Ticker);"

    db.Close
End Sub
```

When I run the above sub I get error:
"Invalid field definition "Ticker" in definition of index or relationship"

UPDATE: What makes this question different is part of the issue I was having was that I needed to have the same field in both tables when I AlTER TABLE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ACCESS VBA - cannot create relations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932761/access-vba-cannot-create-relations)

Comment: Except that I am doing exactly what HansUp suggests in his answer (at least it seems like I am). I have seen that question/answer already. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you confirmed *tbl1* includes a field named *Ticker*?

Comment: Hello HansUp! Don J. just touched on that. I'm sorting out how to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial SQL statement creates an Index named "TickerID" on the field "Ticker." This is why the debug statement returns "Ticker" rather than "TickerID."

Your Foreign Key SQL should be:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tbl1_tbl0 
FOREIGN KEY (Ticker) REFERENCES tbl0 (Ticker);
```

This assumes you have a field in tbl1 named "Ticker" that is the same type as tbl0.Ticker.

The second line in this means the Foreign Key field you are creating references the related key field in the other table. Read it like this: The Foreign Key "Ticker" in the table I am altering (tbl1) references the Primary Key "Ticker" in the related table "tbl0".

I use this routine, which you may find helpful. It does make some assumptions: 1) The Primary Key is always named {table_name} + "Id" and 2) The Foreign Key is usually named the same thing. (both of these are common practice and advisable in my opinion).

```
Public Function CreateForeignKey( _
        db As DAO.Database, _
        ByVal sTable As String, _
        ByVal sPrimaryTable As String, _
        Optional ByVal sField As String) As Boolean

    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim sSuffix As String

    On Error GoTo EH

    If sField = "" Then
        sField = sPrimaryTable & "Id"
    Else
        sSuffix = "_" & sField
    End If

    sSQL = "ALTER TABLE [" & sTable & "]" _
        & " ADD CONSTRAINT FK_" & sTable & "_" & sPrimaryTable & sSuffix _
        & " FOREIGN KEY([" & sField & "])" _
        & " REFERENCES [" & sPrimaryTable & "] ([" & sPrimaryTable & "Id]);"

    db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

    CreateForeignKey = True

    Exit Function
EH:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf _
        & " (" & Err.Source & vbCrLf _
        & " (" & Err.Description _
        & ") in procedure CreateForeignKey of Module Database"

End Function
```

References:

- [CONSTRAINT Clause (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177889(v=office.12).aspx)
- [INDEX Clause (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177891(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I get "Invalid field definition "TickerID" in definition of index or relationship. I also tried "Ticker" instead of "TickerID" and got a similar error.

Comment: Take a look now. This explains what the SQL statement is doing and what parts are what. Decipher the SQL statement and apply using your actual field names. They may both be "Ticker"

Comment: Humm. So your saying I have to add the field "Ticker" to tbl1 before using your SQL, right? I'll try to figure out how to do that and come back here....  <head spinning>

Comment: Yes. A Foreign Key constraint is always created on existing fields. You have at least one field in the foreign table (the one the constraint is in) and at least one key in the related table (the one the primary key is in).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing this all in code? Is this something that is going to have be repeated and dynamic? If not, you might do well to use the GUI to create these. It will also help you understand them better.

Comment: "Is this something that is going to have be repeated and dynamic?" - yes! I have unknown data types, unknown field counts that change, 1350 fields that have to be broken into 6 tables of 250 fields and they almost all have one-to-one relationships. These have to be created each day. Its a challenge/crazy, but I'm up for it.

Comment: In the end this worked well once I added Ticker to both tables; however, 1) I still don't see where "TickerID" went when I created the initial PK, and 2) I don't see the FK in design view for tbl1. I have to go to relationships to see that the foreign key exists. Is there a way to have some indication of the FK when in design view for tbl1 (like how you can see primary keys in design view)?

Comment: No, there is no indication. Generally, the practice is to name them the same as the Primary Key. "TickerID" was the name of your index. The Primary Key can consist of multiple fields (most often it is just one field) in this case named "Ticker" but the Primary Key is an index named "TickerID". You can see the indexes in the table design view. Look for the button with the lightning bolt.

Answer (score 0):

I think your sql should instead be this:

```
 ALTER TABLE tbl1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tbl1_tbl0 
FOREIGN KEY (TickerId) REFERENCES tbl0 (Ticker);
```

The parentId is tickerID and the child is ticker.

Comment: I get "invalid field definition "TickerID" in definition of index or relationthip" when I try that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe old but I found this syntax to work
You want to specify the FK before the PK, although I dont remember why its good pratice to include FKs in PK.

```
Sub CreateTableJours()
On Error Resume Next
    Application.CurrentDb.Execute "Drop Table [Jours];"
'---------------'---------------'
On Error GoTo onError
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Set con = CurrentProject.Connection
    con.Execute "" _
    & "CREATE TABLE [Jours](" _
    & " [jcode]             COUNTER" _
    & ",[jdate]             DATETIME" _
    & ",[tid]               INTEGER" _
    & ",[cid]               INTEGER" _
    & ",[jdepense]          MONEY" _
    & ",[jjustificatif]     CHAR" _
    & ",CONSTRAINT [FK_Taches] FOREIGN KEY ([tid]) REFERENCES Personnes" _
    & ",CONSTRAINT [FK_Chantiers] FOREIGN KEY ([cid]) REFERENCES Chantiers" _
    & ",CONSTRAINT [PK_Jours] PRIMARY KEY ([jcode])" _
    & ");"
    Set con = Nothing
Exit Sub
'---------------'---------------'
onFail:
    myErrorLvl = 250
    Set con = Nothing
Exit Sub
'---------------'---------------'
onError:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Erreur(" & myErrorLvl & ") in " & "INIT.CreateTableJours" & "#" & Err.Number
    If myErrorLvl < 1 Then Resume onFail
End Sub
```